# how to get values of range slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Here i'm having range slider, i got this slider with template,

**Slider Script**

**EDIT**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {                        
// Price Range Input
    $("#price_range").slider({ 
    from: 100,
    to: 10000,
    limits: false, 
    scale: ['$100', '$10,00'],
    heterogeneity: ['50/3000'],
    step: 100,
    smooth: true,
    dimension: '$',
    skin: "round_green",
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
alert('Working');
    }
    });
});
```

[This is the jquery file range slider](http://lotus9.in/click&book/js/jquery.slider.js)
here how can i get values of values of the slider when slider changed...

Please can anyone help me out.

Thanks

Comment: i want the values slider changes...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this one is just a fork of the original one, but according to api you've got several events that you can use to get values while something happens.

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#events